# Show autocomplete list after calling TextBox.AppendText()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete

I have a series of buttons in a winforms dialog (on .net4.5) that append snippets of text to a textbox called `FieldDescription`, like this:

```
private void SnippetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    FieldDescription.AppendText(btn.Text);
    FieldDescription.Focus();
}
```

The textbox has an autocomplete source, and I would like the autocomplete to open after appending the text. The idea is to allow users to easily pre-fill the textbox with the beginning characters of the most used texts. In many cases this means they just have to select an entry from the autocomplete list after clicking the button, without having to use the keyboard.

Is there a way to trigger the autocomplete window after appending the text programmatically like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly I couldn't find a way to do this nicely.

If you can't find a way within .NET you can do it via a p/invoke.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSetCharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]  
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  
private const int CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F;  

SendMessage(FieldDescription.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);
```

You can put it into the `OnFocus` event.

Comment: Thanks Nibbly, I'm having a little trouble though: my TextBox has no `OnFocus` event, so I'm using the `GotFocus` event instead. It gets called correctly after appending the text when I focus the TextBox, but the autocomplete list is not shown. The `SendMessage` command seems not to do anything.

Comment: Well mate, I have tried literally everything, including replicating parts of the source code of the control in an attempt to get the box to show, but absolutely nothing is working. You can sort of workaround it by using `SendKeys`, but the autocomplete only shows if you enter at least one letter. It seems my answer only works on Combobox autocomplete, so you might consider that instead - you may be able to restyle it to look similar.

Comment: Thanks a bundle, I will try it with the ComboBox. Otherwise, from what I was able to find online, a more flexible solution would be to implement my own autocomplete list popup. That way I could control exactly when to show it, even if it is a bit overkill.