# Opening Win32 system AutoComplete programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I use auto completion in a WinForms ComboBox via `AutoCompleteMode` `SuggestAppend` and `AutoCompleteSource` `ListItems`.

When the box is empty and receives Focus I would like the to show the AutoComplete Dropdown immediately.

Note: I do not mean to open the ComboBox dropdown like

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).DroppedDown = true;
}
```

(which is a common answer to this question) because the full dropdown is markably different from the more lightweight AutoComplete dropdown, as seen in the comparison:
[image: DropDown Comparison]

As far as I found, in Win32 the AutoComplete is set up using `SHAutoComplete` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shautocomplete)) from `shlwapi.dll`, however I couldn't find any interaction functions for it.

So, is there a way to open the AutoComplete Dropdown programatically, e.g. via P/Invoke?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Show AutoComplete Programmatically without entering a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920492/how-to-show-autocomplete-programmatically-without-entering-a-text)

Comment: Or actually [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54943771/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for the suggestions. I found those earlier but reason I didn't use them are: The second link is actually equivalent to just using `.DroppedDown = true` which is just the normal dropdown, so not what I was looking for. Remaking the whole thing with another listbox is also quite hacky and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: To add: If the answer is: "There is no way to open the normal system dropdown except for entering a character" then that is ok as well.

Comment: Have you tried to [send keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1264227/1997232)?

Comment: None of the above. You can start from here: [How to make autocomplete on a TextBox show suggestions when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53116401/7444103), get a *better view* of what it takes here: [disable key event when the focus is on autocompletion box of textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12760000/7444103), or implement the [IAutoComplete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete) and [IAutoComplete2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete2) Interfaces (and related stuff) *completely* :)

Comment: There are other *samples* around.  Consider whether you really needs this (not exactly the default behavior - i.e., what Users are accustomed to). I'm not saying that the Autocomplete feature and implementation is *perfect* as it is (also on the devs side), because it's not, by a long shot.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks as well! Seems like there really is no direct way to do it. And I agree with you that it is questionable. In the specific use case it would be good to have the menu I guess, but your notion of familiarity is why I didn't want to use any real custom solution. I think I'll leave it as is for now.

Comment: @Jens "*If the answer is: "There is no way to open the normal system dropdown except for entering a character" then that is ok as well*" - well, `IAutoComplete2` does offer an `ACO_UPDOWNKEYDROPSLIST` option. You could try enabling that option and then simulate a down-arrow key press when needed, for instance.